# How to receive when service is running and update UI after it finish

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to create my service which is downloading data over internet and after the service finishes to send an `intent` in `onDestroy()` and receive it in a tabhost with `broadcastreceiver`, but actually it's never shows the result in `onReceive()`. Here is what I'm doing :

```
package com.stampii.stampii.collections;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;



public class MyService extends Service{

    ThreadSave myThread;
    public static boolean state;

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        MyService getService() {
            return MyService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        myThread = new ThreadSave(this, null);
        myThread.start();
        state = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        state = false;

        Intent intent = new Intent("finish");
        this.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        super.onStart(intent, startid);
    }

}
```

This is my BroadcastReceiver :

```
  receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
         public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          if(intent.getAction().equals("finish")) {
              Log.e("","UGJKHFKLJGHKGKHGKHGKJGLGKLJHKJHVkajhgflasygdfkashfvlazsfklasfylaisyfhg;aisfglafgalskfgl");
               }          
         }
          };

          registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("finish"));
```

and how I start/stop the service :

```
public void getCollectionsInfo(Context context){
 progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 sync.setImageResource(0);

 SharedPreferences isLogged = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = isLogged.edit();
 editor.putBoolean("getProgBarCollection", true);
 editor.commit();

 /*mythreadSync = new ThreadSave(context, mUpdateUpdateCollections, progressBar);
 mythreadSync.start();*/ 

 this.stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
 this.startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));

 }
```

So my question is, am I doing it right and how to get the end of thread which is running in service and update the UI after that on BroadcastReceiver.

Answer (score 0):

You are registering your broadcast receiver using an IntentFilter with "my.db.updated" as the action to filter, but you are sending your intent with "finish" as the action. Either change the intent to "my.db.updated" or change the intent filter to "finish"